# Unable to register Proximity API in Google Developer Console

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-beacon-platform, google-developer-tools

I'm trying to register for `Google Proximity API` in Developer Console. I'm refering [Google Github Link](https://github.com/google/beacon-platform/tree/master/samples/android).

**Current Status :** I've started with the sample project available at the [Google Github Repository](https://github.com/google/beacon-platform). I have created android key and OAuth Client ID using the package name of the project and SHA1 using keytool utility. I'm using the same `advertisedId` as provided in the google documentation.

**Where i'm stuck :** Whenever I'm trying to test the API in the Google API Explorer it is throwing an error `The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects.`

**Request :**

```
POST https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons:register?fields=advertisedId%2Cstatus&key=my_android_api_key    

{
    "advertisedId":
    {
        "id": "Fr4Z98nSoW0hgAAAAAAAAg==",
        "type": "EDDYSTONE"
    },
    "status": "ACTIVE"
}
```

**Response :**

```
400 OK  

{
    "error":
    {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

[image]

I've have already double checked all the package names. They are from the same project which I have downloaded from [Google repository](https://github.com/google/beacon-platform).

Any clue would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is almost certainly that you're authenticating your calls to the API as one user (Google account), but the project was created by an account for a different user.

You have two choices:

1. Authenticate requests to the server with the same Google account that owns the project.
2. Add the user who's doing authentication to the project as somebody who's allowed to make calls against it.

"Authenticating user" in this context is the current active Google account for the app (if you're running an Android sample) or the user who logged in (if you're using iOS). The problem is *that* account isn't in the list of accounts who have permissions to access / modify the project. I believe the Android app lets you select / switch users if you want, while the iOS app definitely has a logout button.

Answer (score 1):

Such type of errors are caused when you are trying to access the API from web application using credentials of different kind of application(in this case Android).
When you create android project in google developer console, the OAuth2.0 and API Key you create will be needed by your actual android app while calling Proximity Beacon API.Create methods in your android app to make use of RESTful calls(i.e beacon.register,etc) to the API.You will be able to register your beacon from your android app.I found this link very useful:[Google-Proximity-Beacons---Part-1](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1755/2015/08/31/google-proximity-beacons---part-1)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to supply both an OAuth client and an API key. I would recommend using only one and then you don't have worry about the OAuth client and key belong to different projects.